# To show transformed problem as convex or not

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, maxima-minima

I have original problem:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\max_{x\geq 0} &\; x \\
\;\text{s.t.}&\; x\leq a  \\
\;\quad & \;\; \log(1+x)\leq b  \\
\;\quad & \;\;a,b\geq 0 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Solution: $x^*=\min\left(a,e^b-1\right)$.

I transform this problem using $\log(1+x)=t$ to have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\max_{t\geq 0} &\; e^t-1 \\
\;\text{s.t.}&\;  e^t-1\leq a  \\
\;\quad & \;\; t\leq b  \\
\;\quad & \;\;a,b\geq 0 \
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Is this problem itself a convex? How can I show that?

Comment: The problem is not convex, because the convex objective gets maximized (instead of minimized). You can make the initial problem convex by rewriting the second constraint to $1+x \leq \exp(b)$.

Comment: How about if I write the objective as $\min 1-e^t$?

Comment: Is that objective convex?